# Hide application on Google play

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, publishing

For testing in app billing i have to publish my application on google play. But i dont want my application to be visible for download, because that in app billing isnt tested and there are some other bugs. Is it possible somehow "hide" the application, but have it in published mode?

Answer (score 2):

To test in app billing, your apk simply needs to be in draft mode.

So you upload the apk but don't click the publish button for your app. If you've already clicked it, click unpublish and the app will be removed from the listings. As long as the apk with the in app billing permission and version code has been uploaded, you will be able to test it.

Comment: Ehm, i think i saw somewhere on stackoverflow, that app must be published. In app products have to be active i suppose, right?

Comment: @user1943012 I dunno about publish. I've tested in app billing in an app of mine when it was unpublished and it worked fine. Your products will only be available to your test accounts when unpublished though.